# Magento 2.3.4 upgrade to 2.3.5 --> Module 'Magento_MysqlMq': Error while checking if topic is synchronous

Tags: magento2

After the upgrade when running setup:upgrade I get this error

Module 'Magento_MysqlMq':
Error while checking if topic is synchronous

In my system.log

[2020-08-27 08:14:18] main.ERROR: Topic "inventory.source.items.cleanup" is not configured. [] []
[2020-08-27 08:21:45] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2020-08-27 08:24:05] main.ERROR: Topic "inventory.source.items.cleanup" is not configured. [] []

Comment: have you resolved this? i'm facing the same issue after installing a plugin